# Circular collection with 2 values

Tags: java

Is there some collection in Java in which I can put 2 objects and then by calling a method on one to return the other one?
Example: myColection [{o1},{o2}]   myCollection.getNext(o1) to retunr o2 and viceversa.

Comment: No. What are you trying to do? What collections did you look at?

Comment: Such a collection wouldn't make much sense and it would be trivial to roll something yourself (it would be a simple `if(param == o1) return o2; else if(param == o2) return o1; else throw Exception;` anyways). - What's the use case for that?

Comment: trying to hit play() on this 2 element collection of 2 players so that each player can move one after another

Comment: In that case I'd recommend rolling your own solution as `next()` will probably not be the only thing you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no collection available in Java which can solve this problem directly. I guess writing own custom logic would be the solution.

I tried something like below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Node{
    String data;
    Node otherNode;
    Node(String data){
        this.data=data;
    }
    Node getOtherNode(){
        return otherNode;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.data;
    }
}


class Ideone
{

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {

    Node first = new Node("FIRST");
    Node second = new Node("SECOND");
    first.otherNode = second;
    second.otherNode = first;

    System.out.println(first.getOtherNode());
  }
}
```

Link to code:https://www.ideone.com/MA7v6L

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Map?

```
public static <T> Map<T, T> alternate(T s1, T s2)
{
    Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(s1,  s2);
    map.put(s2,  s1);
    return map;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map<String, String> map = alternate("hello", "world");

    System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
    System.out.println(map.get("world"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a circular collection of any number of elements, the easiest would be to extend [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) with the methods you want.

This allows you to still use all the normal [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) methods for adding and removing elements to/from the collection.

```
public class CircularArrayDeque<E> extends ArrayDeque<E> {
    public CircularArrayDeque() {
        super();
    }
    public CircularArrayDeque(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }
    public CircularArrayDeque(int numElements) {
        super(numElements);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves the first element of this deque and moves it to the end, or
     * returns {@code null} if this deque is empty.
     * 
     * @return the head of this deque, or {@code null} if this deque is empty
     */
    public E getNext() {
        E elem = pollFirst();
        if (elem != null)
            addLast(elem);
        return elem;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves the last element of this deque and moves it to the front, or
     * returns {@code null} if this deque is empty.
     * 
     * @return the tail of this deque, or {@code null} if this deque is empty
     */
    public E getPrevious() {
        E elem = pollLast();
        if (elem != null)
            addFirst(elem);
        return elem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are looking by for something like a Pair in C++, you need to implement it on your own.

```
class Pair<K, V> {
  private K object1;
  private V object2;

  Pair(K key, V value) {
      this.object1 = key;
      this.object2 = value;
  }

  public K getObject1() {return this.object1;}
  public V getObject2() {return this.object2;}
}

// object initialization 
Pair<String, Integer> p = new Pair("age", 24);
```

Using the above class, you can obtain the necessary functionality.
**If you are looking for a circular list, you can use ArrayList and modify the get method.**

```
class CircularList<T> {
  private List<T> list;
  public CircularList() {
     list = new ArrayList();
  }
  public getNext(int index) {
     return list.get((index+1) % list.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: [Already exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/util/Pair.html).

Comment: I didn't know they added it in Java10. But yeah, if you are not yet there, here is the implementation.

Comment: It was added to the JDK in Java 8.